# How can I speed up gzip compression with h5py?

Tags: performance, compression, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to store the frames of an mp4 video into hdf5 using h5py. At first I tried simply not compressing the data. This caused a 5000 MB video to be about 500 GBs when stored in hdf5. I'm experimenting with using gzip compression to make the dataset more managable, but using the compression it takes about a minute to store a single frame of the video. Here is a minimal code example

```
import h5py
hdf5 = h5py.File(file, mode='a')
dset = hdf5.create_dataset(dset_name, shape=(70000, 1080, 1920, 3), 
    dtype=np.uint8, chunks=True, compression='gzip')

for i, frame in enumerate(video_stream):
    dset[i] = frame
```

Each video has about 70e3 of 1080p rbg images. video_stream is an object that returns (1080, 1920, 3) arrays when iterated over. You can look at it [here](http://pastebin.com/HPmhj902) if you think that's important. So how can I stored this data into hdf5 at a reasonable speed and end up with a reasonable file size? Is it possible to get close to mp4 compression?

Answer (score 2):

MP4 is a quite advanced standard, specifically designed to store video, with often hardware acceleration. You see its efficiency when it manages to pack more than 400 billion values in just 5 billion bytes.

HDF5 is not a video standard, GZip isn't very well suitable for video either. Python probably doesn't matter a lot as the gzip compression is probably in C anyway, but it should be noted that the code is single-threaded. In summary, you're not going to get anything close to MP4.

To be honest, why are you even trying? I suspect you don't have much affinity with video data yet.

Comment: You're correct I don't have a lot of experience with video data. I'm training neural networks on the video data. As of right now I'm just using my VideoStream to pull images from the video files and feed them to the neural network, but it takes a long time to do that and ends up being the bottleneck for my program. I tested transferring one video to hdf5. It's a lot faster, but it takes up too much space. I'm hoping to find a way to quickly pull images from videos without taking about half a TB in storage for each video.

Comment: @mdornfe1: Well, the first thing to realize is that adjacent video frames are very similar, so MP4 doesn't compress individual frames, and therefore decompressing a single frame from MP4 is fairly expensive. Still, your GPU will be quite busy processing one batch of images (you _are_ using a CNN on a GPU?), so just start decompressing the next batch of images on your CPU in parallel.

Comment: Thanks I think that might be the solution.